# Write a list of lists to a table, with the names of each list as a column?

Tags: list, r

I have a fairly basic question about how to write a list to a file.
I have a list generated by Mfuzz acore function, that lists the names of all the probes I have in each of 20 clusters in the following format:

```
[[1]]
         NAME  MEM.SHIP
ILMN_X ILMN_X 0.9993195

.
.
.
[[20]]
         NAME  MEM.SHIP
ILMN_Y ILMN_Y 0.9982345
```

I want to convert it to a data frame and eventually to an output file where the list number is included as a column;

Like this:

```
CLUSTER NAME    MEM.SHIP
      1 ILMN_X 0.9993196
      .
      .
      .
     20 ILMN_Y 0.9982345
```

Where the CLUSTER column indicates which sub-list the probe belongs to.  Each probe name can belong to multible sub-lists.
I have tried different things like suggestions in other posts to use plyr but I always just end up with a single list of all the variables without an indication of which sub-list they belonged to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If your original list is called `clstrs`, I believe this is one solution:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(clstrs), function(i){
  data.frame(CLUSTER=i, clstrs[[i]])
}))
```

Comment: Well, hardly brilliant. But if it worked, you can flag my answer as useful (arrow above the 'score') and/or as the solution (green tickmark)

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way how to skin a cat.

```
# make some sample data
my.df <- data.frame(num = 1:10, val = runif(10))
my.list <- list(my.df, my.df, my.df, my.df, my.df, my.df)
# build index - count the number of rows in each list element that will be 
# used to designate the rows based on their previous list affiliation
index <- lapply(my.list, nrow)
index <- rep(1:length(index), times = index)
# from here on it's basically what Nick did. rbind everything together and
# put some lipstick on and voila
my.out <- do.call("rbind", my.list)
my.out$index <- index
#or
my.out <- cbind(my.out, index)
```

I have a few minutes to spare so I did a quick benchmark using 10e5 rows for each data frame.

My solution with `$index`:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.81    0.27    1.08
```

Solution with `cbind`:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  19.92    0.42   20.38
```

Nick's solution:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   1.04    0.26    1.31
```